# How to duplicate values in the tag in xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt, duplicates

My Code is : We have to fetch the description from paths specified. But duplication occurs in Description1Name;is it possible to remove the duplication?I have approached it which I have put in comments but that does not work.

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:param name="text1" select="PFA/Description1List/Description1Name"/>
      <xsl:param name="text2" select="PFA/Description2List/Description2Name"/>
      <Entity_List Type="LIST_TYPE_CUSTOM_ENTITY" xmlns="https://support.bridgerinsight.lexisnexis.com/downloads/xsd/4.2/CWLEntityExport.xsd">
        <xsl:for-each select="PFA/Records/Person">
          <Entity>
            <First_Name>
              <xsl:value-of select="NameDetails/Name/NameValue/FirstName"/>
            </First_Name>
            <Reason_Listed>
              <xsl:for-each  select="Descriptions/Description" >
                <xsl:variable name="check1" select="@Description1"></xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="check2" select="@Description2"></xsl:variable>
                <!--<xsl:if test="index-of(temp, $check1)!=()">-->
                <xsl:for-each select="$text1">
                  <xsl:if test="$check1=@Description1Id">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    <!--</xsl:call-template>-->
                    <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
                    <!--<xsl:variable name="temp" select="$check1"/>-->
                  </xsl:if>  
                </xsl:for-each>
                <!--</xsl:if>-->
                <xsl:for-each select="$text2">
                  <xsl:if test="$check2=@Description2Id and $check1=@Description1Id ">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
                  </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
              </xsl:for-each>              
            </Reason_Listed>
          </Entity>
        </xsl:for-each>             
        </xsl:template>
```

The Input will is:

```
<Description1List>
  <Description1Name Description1Id="1" RecordType="Person">Politically Exposed Person (PEP)</Description1Name> 
  <Description1Name Description1Id="2" RecordType="Person">Relative or Close Associate (RCA)</Description1Name> 
</Description1List>
<Description2List>
  <Description2Name Description2Id="1" Description1Id="1">Sanctions Lists</Description2Name> 
  <Description2Name Description2Id="2" Description1Id="2">Other Official Lists</Description2Name> 
  </Description2List>
<Records>
    <Person id="196542" action="add" date="19-Jul-2017">
      <Gender>Male</Gender>
      <ActiveStatus>Active</ActiveStatus>
      <Deceased>No</Deceased>
      <NameDetails>
        <Name NameType="Primary Name">
          <NameValue>
            <FirstName>Nourirtg</FirstName>
          </NameValue>
        </Name>
      </NameDetails>
    <Descriptions>
        <Description Description1="1" />
        <Description Description1="1" Description2="1" />
    </Descriptions>
    </Person>
<Records>
```

Thank you:-) in Advance.

Comment: @Rupesh can you help me on this question.

Comment: Can you share the expected output structure?

Comment: My Output is: <Reason_Listed>Politically Exposed Person (PEP);Politically Exposed Person (PEP);Sanctions Lists</Reason_Listed>
Expected Output is: <Reason_Listed>Politically Exposed Person (PEP);Sanctions Lists</Reason_Listed> @AniketV

Comment: Search for "XSLT grouping". With XSLT 1.0, use Muenchian grouping (which is difficult!). With XSLT 2.0, use the xsl:for-each-group instruction. You haven't explained your problem clearly enough for anyone to actually suggest real code.

Comment: My Problem is I have to remove the Duplication in <Reason_Listed>Politically Exposed Per;son (PEP)Politically Exposed Person (PEP);Sanctions Lists</Reason_Listed>. Since I am new to xslt I find it difficult Remove duplicates

Comment: Is this really a case of removing duplicates? In this particular example you can change `<xsl:if test="$check1=@Description1Id">` to `<xsl:if test="$check1=@Description1Id and not(@Description2Id)">`. i.e Only match `@Description1` if there is no `@Description2`?

Comment: no tat is for <xsl:if test="$check1=@Description1Id"> this if is for fetching values from Description1List and not for removing duplicates @Tim C

Comment: What would the expected output be if the second Description tag was `<Description Description1="2" Description2="2" />` instead of `<Description Description1="1" Description2="1" />`?

Comment: This would be the Output: <Reason_Listed>Relative or Close Associate (RCA);Other Official Lists</Reason_Listed>

Comment: @Rupesh I have posted it as a seperate question

Comment: can somone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
 <xsl:key name="Desc" match="PFA/Records/Person/Descriptions/Description[@Description1]" use="@Description1"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:param name="text1" select="PFA/Description1List/Description1Name"/>
      <xsl:param name="text2" select="PFA/Description2List/Description2Name"/>
      <Entity_List Type="LIST_TYPE_CUSTOM_ENTITY" xmlns="https://support.bridgerinsight.lexisnexis.com/downloads/xsd/4.2/CWLEntityExport.xsd">
        <xsl:for-each select="PFA/Records/Person">
          <Entity>
            <First_Name>
              <xsl:value-of select="NameDetails/Name/NameValue/FirstName"/>
            </First_Name>
            <Reason_Listed>
<xsl:if test="generate-id()=generate-id(key('Desc', @Description1)[1])">
              <xsl:for-each  select="Descriptions/Description" >
                <xsl:variable name="check1" select="@Description1"></xsl:variable>
                <xsl:variable name="check2" select="@Description2"></xsl:variable>
                <!--<xsl:if test="index-of(temp, $check1)!=()">-->
                <xsl:for-each select="$text1">
                  <xsl:if test="$check1=@Description1Id">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    <!--</xsl:call-template>-->
                    <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
                    <!--<xsl:variable name="temp" select="$check1"/>-->
                  </xsl:if>  
                </xsl:for-each>
              </xsl:if>
                <xsl:for-each select="$text2">
                  <xsl:if test="$check2=@Description2Id and $check1=@Description1Id ">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                    <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
                  </xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
              </xsl:for-each>              
            </Reason_Listed>
          </Entity>
        </xsl:for-each>             
        </xsl:template>
```

Comment: I got the result using key. but is there a way to reset the after each <xsl:for-each select="PFA/Records/Person"> loop?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   <Reason_Listed>
        <xsl:for-each select="Descriptions/Description">
            <xsl:variable name="check1" select="@Description1"/>
            <xsl:variable name="check2" select="@Description2"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="@Description2">
                    <xsl:value-of
                        select="$text2[@Description2Id = $check2 and @Description1Id = $check1]"
                    />
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="$text1[@Description1Id = $check1]"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
            <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
                <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </Reason_Listed>
```

Just edit your first code.